# PlasticSCM fast import: Octal escaped file names when importing from git svn

Tags: plasticscm

I'm currently evaluating PlastiSCM. One of our evaluation tasks is to test migration from our SVN repository to Plastic. We want to migrate our trunk only since the branch structure and information is somewhat broken.

I was able to migrate to git with git svn. I fast exported the git repo with -C -M parameters. The import into PlasticSCM succeeded. However, when checking out \master on the imported Plastic Repo, the client complains about missing files. These files don't show up in the "Items" list in the Client.

The filenames which have issues contain octal escape sequences. It turned out that these file names have got german umlaute (ä, ö, ü) in them. I was testing git fast import of the exported stream. Git is able to handle theses filenames correctly.

After some digging I found this aged thread: [Fast export/import issues](http://www.plasticscm.net/index.php?/topic/618-fast-export-failing-to-deal-with-non-english-chars-in-branch-names/page-2#entry5711). I've linked to a post telling about the octal coding issue. The thread is actually adressing TFS conversion issues in general.

One author claims to have a script which recodes octal coded characters into an encoding which can be read by PlasticSCM fast import. However, the script is not provided.

Has anyone encountered this problem as well? How could a solution look like? I can't imagine I'm the only one having this problem, especially because Plastic is developed in Spain where non-english characters should encounter quite frequently. I wonder whether this issues is known and tracked by the Plastic SCM development team.

Comment: You can find the requested script here:
http://www.plasticscm.net/index.php?/topic/930-importing-tfs-project-into-plastic/page-2

Anyway, could send your fast-export file to:  support at codicesoftware dot com ?
We will review your scenario in detail, and we will try to modify the file in order to properly import it to Plastic. I guess that you ar using the last Plastic 5.4 version, right?

PD: You can use the "--nodata" option if you can´t share with us your repository content.

Comment: I'll check if I can provide you the requested data. The link you provided is the thread mentioned by me. I can see a script there, but it seems to me that it handles missing quotes only.

Comment: P.S.: I've installed the latest version of PlasticSCM (5.4.16.633)

Comment: I've looked into the nodata-export. I'm afraid my company won't release that kind of information without NDA since it provides information about internal development structures. Anyway, I'll try the script you mentioned (I've realized the thread you linked was different to my reference)